# Steam Engine Resets COD Black Ops Level

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-black-ops

Hoping someone might be able to me with this.

I play CoD: Black Ops multi-player on-line a bit, I think I'm a prestige 5 level 47? Or at least I was, until Steam reset my settings.

I had some internet trouble, but after one bout, steam synchronization says it couldn't sync my files and to keep playing. So I select to keep playing, and it's fine. Until today, when I played and all of a sudden I was back to prestige 0 level 1 in the middle of the game. And no matter how many times I restart, it hasn't come back.

I've sunk a fair bit of time into this game, so I'd like to know if I can get my score back.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this exact same problem before with Steam Cloud, but with the game Brink instead. What you need to do is sync your game with Steam Cloud. This will solve your problem by resetting your game back to the previous save that's floating around up there in Steam Cloud, which in this case is your level 47 character.  HOW TO DO THIS: Right click on Black Ops in Steam Library, and click properties. After that, click the Updates tab, and uncheck the box that says `Enable Steam Cloud synchronization for Call of Duty: Black Ops`, close that window, than enter properties for BlOps again, check the box, and exit. There may be a prompt asking if you want to restore, etc. and just click "Yes". That should restore your character to it's previous glory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed follow-up! Unfortunately, it appears this does not work. A strange situation has occurred: I currently have access to all of my advanced weaponry / configurations, but other things it says I can't unlock until I reach level one. It definitely is a sync issue, but this particular remedy didn't appear to work. Thank you for taking the time, and I'd love to hear any other ideas you have about it!

Comment: Hmmmmm... I am thinking that you should try to restore your BlOps to an even more previous completion save, if that is possible. If you have multiple options in the Steam Cloud saved games list, pick one that is a good amount of time from when this problem started occurring, and try restoring to that. If there are no previous/other saves in the Cloud, that option is down the toilet. If that is the case, contact Steam Support; this is really weird, and this is something that Steam needs to know about to work on to prevent this problem re-appearing with other people and other games.